# Is there any compatibility issues with adaptivecards text formatting in mobiles at teams application?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, web-chat

We are using botframework webchat for developing a bot in teams as well as web via directline channel. Everything is fine in web and teams but when coming to teams in mobile devices, adaptive cards formatting is not working as same as web.
[image: ac in mobile devices]

[image: in desktop]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

```
  {
 "type": "AdaptiveCard",
 "version": "1.0",
 "body": [
 {
 "type": "Container",
 "id" : "qna_card",
 "items": [
 {
 "type": "TextBlock",
 "text": ans[1],
 "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
 "color": "Accent",
 "weight": "Bolder",
 "size": "Medium"
 },
 {
 "type": "TextBlock",
 "text": ans[2],
 "wrap": true,
 "color": "Default"
 },
 {
 "type": "ActionSet",
 "actions": [
 {
 "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
 "title": read_more,
 "url": ans[3],
 "style": "positive"
 }
 ],
 "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
 }
 ]
 }
 ],
 "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
 "id" : "qna_card_id"
 }
```

Comment: can you add a sample of the AC source / json ?
also : can you clarify which of the 2 examples is rendered on which platform ?

Comment: The first example is on the teams app in mobile device and second one is on the teams app of desktop. And the adaptivecards json is same for both devices.

Comment: and can you add / link to the json ?

Comment: Can we have JSON to repro this issue?

Comment: yes, I have just added it in the question. Can you please check once

Comment: @Susmitha Kongalla, Could you please add json in text format, image won't work for us to repro this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @SusmithaKonagalla please help us help you. 
Please take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [no images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for some tips and suggestions.

Comment: yes I have added the json code and sorry for inconvinience.

Comment: Could you please provide same json which, I see complete different json that has been posted here.